# CubeSurfer Replacement for 2.8?

Tags: mesh, particles, add-on

CubeSurfer add-on by Pyroevil currently does not work with Blender 2.8, so I am searching for a good replacement, but my searches have come up dry.

OR

If any of ya'll have figured out a way to force CubeSurfer to work, I'd be really happy with that as well.

I'm currently just using the metaball method, but the results aren't nearly as clean as CubeSurfer when making fluids with particles.

Answer (score 1):

I found it in case you still need it. You can download a zip from the GitHub page at https://github.com/porkminer/CubeSurfer, but it gives you an error when you try to istall it in Blender. I fixed it by changing the line `from cubesurfer import mciso` just to `import mciso`. The download link is https://gofile.io/?c=sEWqb3.